# How to putFiles in firebase with Content Provider (content://) as source?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I know from this 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

that putFile() function requires Uri from file:// protocol. How can I do upload files from content:// protocol (as provided by FileProvider)?

Comment: what code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this tutorial, is very useful:

Click [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/)

I hope it helps you!